# Raspberry Pi don't asking me for password when using sudo

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sudo

Since alot of time, my Raspbian install is no longer asking me my password while using `sudo`, and that's a security issue because it can be accessed remotly.
I searched on Google how to **enable** that, but the only things I seen is how to **disable** that.
After logging in using `ssh`:

```
pi@WS-RPI-10666:~ $ sudo echo a
a
pi@WS-RPI-10666:~ $
```

Regards,
Minteck

Comment: `is no longer asking me my password` - so it used to and stopped? That means you edited `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: I never edited `/etc/sudoers`, I think that feature broke during an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `sudo` is not asking for password that means you probably have
`NOPASSWD` in `/etc/sudoers`. As described in `man 5 sudoers`:

> NOPASSWD and PASSWD
>
> By default, sudo requires that a user authenticate him or herself
>   before running a command.  This behavior can be modified via the
>   NOPASSWD tag.  Like a Runas_Spec, the NOPASSWD tag sets a default for
>   the commands that follow it in the Cmnd_Spec_List.  Conversely, the
>   PASSWD tag can be used to reverse things.

Never edit `/etc/sudoers` directly, run `sudo visudo` instead. Locate
a line that sets permissions for a specific user you're interested,
say `pi`:

```
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And remove `NOPASSWD:` part:

```
pi ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Save the changes and re-run a test command with `sudo`, it should require
a password now.

Comment: Tip for other people: If the line isn't on the fine, just add it. (Thanks)

Comment: just changed my sudoers file and still it doesnt ask for a password, now i found `/etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd`... after removing that file it finally works

Comment: remember to set a password for yourself before doing this

Answer (score 4):

For Debian bullseye edition

we cannot find 'NOPASSWD:' in /etc/sudoers

it should be in /etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd

so you can edit it by

```
sudo visudo /etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd
```

and change

```
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

to

```
pi ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

(remove 'NOPASSWD:')

and save and close...

if you make any mistake, it will promt that... press <kbd>e</kbd> to go back to editing
NEVER PRESS <kbd>q</kbd>!!!